# Problemas con SetTag() en Android Studio

Tags: android, listview

Estoy llenando datos a un listview y me sale un error cuando estoy realizado el siguiente código con el error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.tuinen.carlosvilla.tuinensoft, PID:
>   21682 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'android.widget.TextView
>   com.tuinen.carlosvilla.tuinensoft.BandasAdapter$BandasHolder.texto' on
>   a null object reference

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Carlos!, agrega el codigo y no como imagen para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Answer (score 1):

Cuando `convertView` es `null`, significa que no hay una vista en el reciclado, por lo tanto debemos crear uno nuevo. Tu `Holder` tiene 2 atributos visuales `ImageView` y un `TextView`. La función del adaptador en si, es para reutilizar vistas. Por lo tanto una vez que se cargo un item de tu lista, no es necesario nuevamente definir esta vista, si no que ya esta en reciclado y basta con setear los valores de tus distintos items. Tu codigo evalua que no sea `null`, si es `null` defines este formato de vista para que los demas items lo carguen, si es que es distinto de `null`, solo tomas el que ya creaste anteriormente con `getTag()`.

El error esta en el `else` donde haces

```
holder = (BandasHolder) row.setTag();
```

Cambia por :

```
holder = (BandasHolder) row.getTag();
```

Comment: Hey ya editaste tu respuesta en base a la mia! ᗒ ͟ʖᗕ

Comment: @Elenasys no la edite en base a la tuya :0!! , solo documente como funciona el adaptador, porque se verifica si es o no nulo, me diste un consejo y lo segui :3

Answer (score 0):

Basado en el error:

> Attempt to read from field 'android.widget.TextView
>   com.tuinen.carlosvilla.tuinensoft.BandasAdapter$BandasHolder.texto' on
>   a null object reference

Si no existe `ConvertView` (`row`), crea contenedor a partir de su etiqueta mediante, obtenida mediante `getTag()`:

```
if(row == null){ //ConvertView es null.
   ... 
   ...
    row.setTag(holder); //Agrega tag al ConvertView.
} else {
    holder = (BandasHolder) convertView.getTag(); //Crea contenedor a partir de su Etiqueta.
   //o también holder = (BandasHolder) row.getTag();
}
```

Comment: porque utilizar convertView.getTag(), cuando row ya tiene su valor? que diferencia hay con mi respuesta?

Comment: Hay que documentar lo más posible. el ConvertView y el row es lo mismo por lo tanto se puede usar cualquiera.